# Automake linking modules

Tags: gcc, gnu, ld, autoconf, automake

I have a problem with automake/autoconf. I will show you the layout of my source tree first:

src 
------arch 
----------avr
--------------i2c.c
-------sys
-----------thread.c

Now my problem. It isn't that hard to fully compile arch/avr/i2c.c and sys/thread.c. But what i actualy want is to compile all my sub directories partialy (with gcc -c) and then link all objects from one subdir together (ld -r) and make a program of of those subdirectory object files when all subdirectories are compiled. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Greetz,
Michel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Automake has no support for `ld -r`, and I don't think `libtool` can do it either.  The usual setup is to build one static archive per directory, and link the main program with these static archives.

You could have in `arch/avr/Makefile.am`

```
noinst_LIBRARIES = libavr.a
libavr_a_SOURCES = i2c.c ...
```

something similar in `sys/`, and `src/Makefile.am` would look like

```
SUBDIRS = arch sys .
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = main
foo_LDADD = arch/avr/libavr.a sys/libsys.a
```

Comment: And I guess i can use xxx_LIBADD=libName.a to recusivly build up a library.

Comment: Automake only knows how to build a static archive from objects.  If you want to lump archives together recursively, you should use Libtool convenience libraries instead: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Libtool-Convenience-Libraries.html